# How to transer/execute a script on remote Unix server from Linux machine

Tags: security, passwords, login

I am trying to deploy an executable and execute it on a remote Unix machine (Linux/Solaris) from Linux without entering the password manually.

I tried scp and also SSH key-gen utility to interact with remote server but in either way I couldn't avoid providing the password manually. Since I need to run this command/utility from Java code, I should completely avoid prompting for the password at run time. I have gone through many topics in Google but nothing has materialized.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You should set up authentication using public/private keypair as you already mentioned you generated using `ssh-keygen`. Have it generated without a password on the private key if you need to use it in automated scripts. Now, just copy over the public key using `ssh-copy-id name@host` to set it up correctly on the remote side (authorize public key).

I suggest you to follow a tutorial like [this one](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/3-steps-to-perform-ssh-login-without-password-using-ssh-keygen-ssh-copy-id/).

If `ssh` works, then `scp` works likewise.

After setting it up correctly, you should be able to do this without interaction:

```
scp myscript.sh name@remotehost:~/
ssh name@remotehost ~/myscript.sh
```

---

To avoid having to enter a password or passphrase there are a couple of choices

- use an authentication agent to hold the password/passphrase for the private key
- don't use any pass-phrase to protect the private key

The first is appropriate for interactive use, the latter is less secure. You should probably set up a new user-id for this with  minimal rights at the far end (e.g. chrooted)

Comment: You beat me to it. I'll merge my (now deleted) answer into yours, please undo if you object.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read about rhosts and rlogin.

http://vegdave.wordpress.com/2007/05/17/how-to-rloginrcprsh-to-a-machine-without-enter-a-password/

Comment: Is this secure? It seems a sort of unencrypted remote shell.

Answer (score 0):

Step 0. You must have ssh access to remote machine.

Step 1. Generate RSA private/public key pair with `ssh-keygen` on your Linux box and place it somewhere (/root/identities, for example). Provide no passphrase.

Step 2. `ssh-copy-id -i /root/identities/your.key user@remotemachine.tld`

Step 3. This is it. Now you may `ssh -i /root/identities/your.key user@remotemachine your_command` and no password would be prompted. Sure, you must have `PubkeyAuthentication = yes` in remote machine's `sshd_config`.